# Group of radio in a list flutter

Tags: flutter

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "categories 1",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "sub 2"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "sub 3 "
       
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "categories 2",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "categories 3",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 222,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 229,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 229,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need list of categories in a radio button but it is working but only one radio button is getting selected all the time but i need to select one radio button for each time here is my radio button part i have achieved all but only one radio button is getting selected , here is part of code

//it will come in a 2 nd list

```
 RadioListTile(
              value: pr[index].child[ind2].id,
              groupValue: selectedRadioValue,
              // dense: true,
              //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedRadioValue = value;
                 
              },
            ),
```

SO i click any option button only one is selected but i need each category should be selected  1

```
 children: List.generate(prlist[index].length, (ind2) {
                  return bundleradio(
                      prlist[index],ind2);
                }),
```

Comment: share your list view builder method.

Comment: updated my list builder